# Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix with characteristic polynomial $x^3-3x+a$, for what values of $a$ given matrix must be diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, characteristic-polynomial

Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix with characteristic polynomial $x^3-3x+a$. For what values of $a$ given matrix must be diagonalizable.

I am talking about diagonalizability over reals.
Efforts:

If a matrix has distinct eigenvalues, then matrix is diagonalizable. But how can I use this information.

I also know that if char. polynomial is $x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$, then $-a_2=\mbox{trace}(A) \mbox{ and } -a_0=\det(A).$

I am not able to proceed.

Can someone please give a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want "diagonal" or just "diagonalizable" in the title?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have edited the post. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 6):

Let $p(x)=x^3-3x+a$. If $p(x)$ has a multiple root, then that root will also be a root of $p'(x)$. But the roots of $p'(x)$ are $\pm1$. So,\begin{align}p(x)\text{ has a multiple root}&\iff\pm1\text{ is a root of }p(x)\\&\iff a=\pm2.\end{align}So, check only these two cases.

Comment: $|a|>2$ gives complex roots.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:*
A cubic has three distinct real roots iff its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#The_discriminant) is positive.
The discriminant of $x^3-3x+a$ is $\Delta=-27 (a^2 - 4)$.

Comment: so $a$ lies between $-2$ and $2$!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: compute the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial.